# How to get pages id and connected instagram account in facebook api version 18.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm having a web application to help users post on instagram. My app currently registers two permissions to use facebook graph api, pages_show_list and instagram_basic.

- In api version 16.0, I can completely get information about pages'id and instagram account information by /me/accounts endpoint. But in version 18.0 /me/accounts always response empty. Please see 2 images below

[/me/accounts in 16.0 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2xl3.png)

[me/accounts in 18.0 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXIUy.png)

Can anyone help me how to get pages'id and connected instagram id in version 18.0 and What permissions do I need exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the permission, `business_management`.